# How to use CTE into IN clause?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

i want get all children of my category and merge with Contents.
at mean i want when i click a category, show all contents of category and subcategories.
i used CTE and it is:

```
WITH ret AS (SELECT     id, parent
                         FROM        ContentsGroups
                         WHERE     (id = @id)
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT     t.id, t.parent
                         FROM         ContentsGroups AS t INNER JOIN
                                               ret AS r ON t.parent = r.id)
SELECT     id
 FROM         ret
```

how can i join the output to my Contents table?

when i use these:

```
SELECT title FROM Contents WHERE id IN (WITH ret AS ... )
```

i get error related With clause
How can i Merge With clause with my Table?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH ret AS (SELECT     id, parent
                         FROM        ContentsGroups
                         WHERE     (id = @id)
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT     t.id, t.parent
                         FROM         ContentsGroups AS t INNER JOIN
                                               ret AS r ON t.parent = r.id)

SELECT title FROM Contents WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ret);
```

Comment: The query you posted above is that complete code? can you post actual SQL error?